# Auto scroll appears after reach height

Tags: jquery, html

I have `div` which show the list whos online and I want show the scroll bar when my data shows `10`, the default of my `div` is no data. It means data will appear when users are online.

The problem is when there is `1000` users online? My `div` will be too long.

I have tried with this CSS:

```
#isi_menu_kanan{
    height: 100px;
    overflow: show;
}
```

But its means I set the default `height` of the div and if no user is online the div appears with the null data. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: overflow: show is the default CSS property, therefore you do not need to define it.  Also 100px is an exact height don't forget to consider accessibility for those who view larger font-sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question you're trying to have a `div` which contains 1000s of line, but is only `100px` high? In that case you need to use `overflow: scroll`.

Try this:

```
#isi_menu_kanan{
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eDXe2/)

Note, I've also used `max-height`. This means that if there is only 1 line in the `div` the height will contract to fit. jQuery and javascript is not needed here.